# Color Space options for CIContext

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, core-image

When creating a Core Image [CIContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIContext/contextWithCGLContext:pixelFormat:colorSpace:options:) using the following:

```
contextWithCGLContext:pixelFormat:colorSpace:options:
```

You can specify a color space with a `CGColorSpaceRef`. However, the `options` dictionary that you can pass also allows you to set certain color space parameters. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Context_Options):

> `kCIContextOutputColorSpace`
>
> A key for the color space to use for images before they are rendered
>   to the context. By default, Core Image uses the GenericRGB color
>   space, which leaves color matching to the system. You can specify a
>   different output color space by providing a Quartz 2D CGColorSpace
>   object (CGColorSpaceRef). (See Quartz 2D Programming Guide for
>   information on creating and using CGColorSpace objects.)
>
> `kCIContextWorkingColorSpace`
>
> A key for the color space to use for image operations. By default,
>   Core Image assumes that processing nodes are 128 bits-per-pixel,
>   linear light, premultiplied RGBA floating-point values that use the
>   GenericRGB color space. You can specify a different working color
>   space by providing a Quartz 2D CGColorSpace object (CGColorSpaceRef).
>   Note that the working color space must be RGB-based. If you have YUV
>   data as input (or other data that is not RGB-based), you can use
>   ColorSync functions to convert to the working color space. (See Quartz
>   2D Programming Guide for information on creating and using
>   CGColorSpace objects.)

My question is, how do these various color space parameters interact?

My assumption would be that creating the CIContext with with a color space set using the `colorspace:` parameter above would be the same as setting the color space using the `kCIContextOutputColorSpace` in the `options:` dictionary. Is that correct? If not, what does each parameter mean?

If so, then what happens if the color space is set using both the `colorspace:` parameter as well as the `kCIContextOutputColorSpace` key in the `options:` dictionary? Does one override the other? Is there some other behavior?